# (GDPR) Asp.net core ITrackingConsentFeature not working properly with cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, gdprconsentform, cookieconsent

I'm using asp.net core MVC with TargetFramework net5.0.

I'm implementing ***EU General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) support in ASP.NET Core***.

I exactly implemented this article
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-3.1.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

But when I set `document.cookie` by `cookieString` then nothing happened.

I figured out this issue is related to `cookieString` that generated by `consentFeature?.CreateConsentCookie()`.

Because the separation here is `;` so I change that with `.Replace(";", ",")`.

It's work now but I faced an issue with expiration DateTime. It's not working anymore. It's equal to
***When the browsing session ends***

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found another answer to that.

The problem in related to cookieString when I want to add in to the document.cookie.

```
@{
    var consentFeature = Context.Features.Get<ITrackingConsentFeature>();
    var showBanner = !consentFeature?.CanTrack ?? false;
    var cookieString = consentFeature?.CreateConsentCookie();
}
```

I just a added ***cookieString*** as a string with the end of double quation end of the string.

```
document.cookie = `${button.dataset.cookieString}"`;
```

I don't know It's a good way or not but It works.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well... Weird, that the most common sample on this simply does not work.